# Most efficient place to store "template" variables in OOP for a single-use function

Tags: php, performance, oop, processing-efficiency

Large, multi-line variables but not large enough where you'd consider loading them externally. Would it be within the single use function as opposed to adding it to the class itself?

```
class MyClass{
    var $tpl = 'ALOT OF TEXT HERE';
```

or within a class function

```
function MyFunction()
{
    $tpl = 'ALOT OF TEXT HERE';
```

I'm all for better readability/maintainability by placing static variables at the top of classes, but not if it slows things down.

Comment: What does "large" mean? Is the program to be stored on punched cards? And are you having performance problems? If not, then why are you worrying about this?

Comment: Multiple lines or a significant amount to store. Nothing like that, I guess I never heard "if it ain't broke don't fix it." So I take it there is little difference in performance as far as where variables go?

Comment: Where to put it has more to do with where it makes most sense to put it. Performance plays almost no part. If it is part of the object itself then having it as a property would make sense. If it is only used inside a method then put it there. If it is very long, or used elsewhere in your code base, then storing it elsewhere may make more sense, in order to keep the class' code more tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your particular use case it may be both, but for three reasons I would opt for function.

Firstly if you put it as a class variable, then it will be instantiated for every single instance (unless it is class side).

Secondly having it as a variable would imply that you want to change it. Since PHP doesn't have `final`, you can't really tell those two apart. Since it is supposed to be a template, changing it for everyone may not be wanted.

Thirdly, having it a method helps with hiding the implementation. If you at later time decide to move it to separate file, database or wherever, then you can just change the behavior of the function returning it without affecting the clients.